# Finding the volume of a tetrahedron using calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wanted to find the volume of a tetrahedron given a side length of 5. By using geometry, I could see that the formula in question is $\frac{x^3\sqrt{2}} {12}$ or $ \frac{x^3}{6\sqrt{2}}$

But when I used calculus I didn't get the same answer: $ \int_0^{5} \int_0^{5-x} \int_0^{5-x-y} dz dy dx$ which yields $\frac{125}{6}$ I'm missing the $\sqrt{2}$ term in the denominator.

Comment: That wouldn't be a tetrahedron.  The side opposite the origin would be too big.

Comment: @user361424: Well, it's a tetrahedron; it's just not a regular tetrahedron, in the same way that $\int_{x=0}^5 \int_{y=0}^{5-x} dy\,dx$ would yield the area of a right isosceles triangle, not an equilateral (i.e., regular) triangle.